# Unable to change global language setting in App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a couple of language files and the translations are working

But when I try to change the language, I am unable to make the app re-render.

Should I subscribe and listen to a change, or is there a better way?

PS, this app is [open source](https://github.com/OpenLitterMap/react-native/blob/master/App.js). We would love your help.

```
import { LanguageProvider } from 'react-native-translation'
import { langs } from './assets/langs';

import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";
let lang = RNLocalize.getLocales()['languageCode'];
if (lang !== 'de' && lang !== 'en' && lang !== 'nl' && lang !== 'es') lang = 'en'

import RootContainer from './screens/RootContainer'

const App: () => React$Node = () => {

    const { persistor, store } = configureStore();

    // on first render, we want to init current lang
    store.dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_LANG', lang });

    // if the language changes, we want to update langs[lang]

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                <LanguageProvider language={lang} defaultLanguage={"en"} translations={langs[lang]}>
                    <RootContainer key={lang} />
                </LanguageProvider>
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by passing all translations into the LanguageProvider

Storing the current language on redux

and instead of using `welcome.hello` I am using `lang.welcome.hello`

Not perfect but it works for now